# How much RAM can a website in iOS Safari use

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, webkit, ram

I am developing a browser-based [photo editor Photopea](https://www.Photopea.com). Many iOS users report, that it crashes on their iPads (latest iOS, 4 GB of RAM). Users work with large documents (big resolution, many layers) and Photopea may require 2 - 3 GB of RAM.

- Is it known how much RAM websites are allowed to use in iOS Safari? Could you maybe test it on your iPad?
- What is the best way to make Apple fix it?

Comment: Did you find out the limit? I'm currently interested in this too.

Answer (score 0):

- iOS Safari uses 200-400MB RAM memory
- you can not develop an application that req memory in GB